# AWS GraphQL error: "message": "Variable 'customerId' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'"

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

The Error message kept telling me I don't have the right input for the customerId, but I'm actually passing id based on the GraphQL definition.

The error message is "message": "Variable 'customerId' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'"

GraphQL:

```
export const assignUsersToCustomer = `
mutation assignUsersToCustomer($customerId: ID!, $user_ids: [ID!]!) {
  assignUsersToCustomer(id: $customerId, user_ids: $user_ids) {
    id
    users {
      id
    }
    organization_id
  }
}`;
```

Code sample:

```
const userDetail = {
    id: customerId,
    user_ids: assignedUserIds.concat(user.id),
  };

const assignUser = async () => {
    await API.graphql({
      query: mutations.assignUsersToCustomer,
      variables: {input: userDetail},
    });
  };

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.listItem}>
          {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => assignUser()}>
        <Icon name="add-circle-outline" size={30} color={Colors.primary} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: change qoery `$id: ID!` ... `id: $id`... and use `variables: userDetail` ...... or `variables: { customerId: userDetail.id, user_ids: userDetail.user_ids }` w/o query changes

Comment: ... and as always ... test in playground using 'query variables' before coding